# How to put tabularx inside tabularx with different column length

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to nest a `tabularx` table into a cell of another `tabularx` table. I did it according to the Question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151245/how-to-put-tabularx-inside-tabularx). Now my problem is, that they use the `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` column type, which does not allow to specify the width of the columns.

My definitions look like this:

```
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}
```

If I use one of them, the nested table will overflow the cell. Do you have any idea how I could fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{minted}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{L{0.6}L{1.4}}
    \toprule
      \textbf{Command} & \textbf{Description} \\
    \midrule
      \mintinline{console}{pwd} & Print name of current working directory test trest \\
      \mintinline{console}{cd} & {
        Change directory
        \newline
        \begin{tabularx}{\cellwidth}{L{0.8}L{1.2}}
          \toprule
          \mintinline{console}{~} & current users home directory \\
          \mintinline{console}{~bob} & bobs' home direcotry \\
          \mintinline{console}{-} & previous directory \\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        } \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Basics}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Now it looks like this:
[image: The table]

How can I extend the nested table to the edge of the cell?

Comment: Beware: the total of the `\hize`s must equal the number of `X` columns, so that, for instance, in the nested tabularx, the coefficients should be `0.6` and `1.4`.

Comment: @Bernard ah thanks for the hint. So I did it wrong all those years... The second table is now contained in the cell. But now it does not fill to the edge.

Comment: I must say the documentation for this point needs to be read carefully. B.t.w., also, in your outer tabularx, `L{0.5}L{0.5}` is simply `XX`.

Comment: How is the `\mintinline` macro defined?

Comment: its in the `\usepackage{minted}` package

Comment: How is `\cellwidth` defined?

Comment: @leandriis `\newcommand{\cellwidth}{\TX@col@width}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are three different possibilities how you can achieve the desired layout. Please note that I have removed the `\mintinline` commands as the issue is reproducible without them.

In the first table, I have replaced the undefined `\cellwidth` with `1.4\linewidth+\tabcolsep`. In this case, `1.4` equals the option of the second column of the surrounding [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx).

In the second table, I have used just one variable width column per [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) as the left columns of both the outer and the inner table don't seem to contain content that needs to be automatically broken over several lines.

In the third table, I have completely removed the inner [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and used `\multicolumn` commands instead.

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{calc}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\hsize=#1\hsize\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{L{0.6}L{1.4}}
    \toprule
      \textbf{Command} & \textbf{Description} \\
    \midrule
      \texttt{pwd} & Print name of current working directory test trest \\
      \texttt{cd} & {
        Change directory
        \newline
        \begin{tabularx}{1.4\linewidth+\tabcolsep}{L{0.8}L{1.2}}
          \toprule
          \texttt{\~} & current users home directory \\
          \texttt{bob} & bobs' home direcotry \\
          \texttt{-} & previous directory \\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        } \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Basics}
\end{table}

 \begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
    \toprule
      \textbf{Command} & \textbf{Description} \\
    \midrule
      \texttt{pwd} & Print name of current working directory test trest \\
      \texttt{cd} & {
        Change directory
        \newline
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth+\tabcolsep}{lX}
          \toprule
          \texttt{\~} & current users home directory \\
          \texttt{bob} & bobs' home direcotry \\
          \texttt{-} & previous directory \\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        } \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Basics}
\end{table}

 \begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llX}
    \toprule
      \textbf{Command} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{\textbf{Description}} \\
    \midrule
      \texttt{pwd} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{Print name of current working directory test trest }\\
      \texttt{cd}  & \multicolumn{2}{X}{Change directory}\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
                   & \texttt{\~}     & current users home directory \\
                   &  \texttt{bob}   & bobs' home direcotry \\
                   & \texttt{-}      & previous directory \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Basics}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]