# Full-width tabular with column width as needed

Tags: tabularx, minipage

I am translating HTML-tables to latex counterparts.

In HTML, I have a table with full width that distributes the column according to their content.

So this leads to equally spaced columns,

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

whereas this assigns 4 times as much space to the left column:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>aaaa</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See also here for a nested example: https://jsfiddle.net/49nhmqLu/1/

## tabularx

I have found that for `tabularx` an `X` column takes the remaining space:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
```

but there multiple `X`-columns would distribute the width equally, not as needed by the content. (`XX` would be 50:50, `XXX` would be 33:33:33)

**My question**: Is it possible to have a column type that distributes width relatively to the content? like my `aaaa - a` (i.e. 80:20 here) example?

## Additional requirement

Actually, the content of the tabular cells may itself consist of `tabularx`'s . So I have found that tabularx-in-tabularx seems to be impossible.

If I use outer `tabulars`, i can only arrive at full textwidth by having minipages inside:

If I do not insist on the content-aware column widths, I can use `tabular` outside and use `minipages` with fixed widths (eg two columns with `.47\textwidth` each) inside.

```
\begin{tabular}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\columnwidth}
left outer
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\columnwidth}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    inner left &
    inner right
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\\
\end{tabular}
```

I am absolutely clueless how to get an automatic width distribution to work here, the latter example will always be 50:50.

Note that I am not insiting on an outer tabular. Anything else that distributes with according to content is fine as well. In HTML one could use e.g. `<div>`'s here

In the best case there would exist an environment `tabularxyz` which allows:

```
\begin{tabularxyz}
  left outer
&
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    inner left &
    inner right
  \end{tabularx}
\\
\end{tabularxyz}
```

where Latex determines the optimal width for all columns, just as `tabulary` does this (but only for plain text contents).

The nested `tabularx`'s  are the result of a placeholder substitution from my reporting software. Most of the time, they are even just used without a surrounding table. I use tabularx because it allows to use full available textwidth.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I didn't understand what the problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: I improved my question

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it seems to me that what you want is the default behavior of the `tabular` environment.

Comment: You could take a look at the `tabulary` package.

Comment: Indeed, tabulary or tabular*, depending on if  full witdh is a maximum limit or the goal.

Comment: Thanks @leandriis, this works well for plain text contents, but I need to nest `tabularx`'s inside the cells, and that seems to be incompatible with tabulary.

Comment: Could you please add an example that clearly shows why you would need tabularx inside or another table cell? The current example could also be solved in  a different way.

Comment: Regarding "tabularx-in-tabularx seems to be impossible": [How to put tabularx inside tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151256/134144) might be interesting. Unfortunately this does not seem to be adaptable to `tabulary`.

Comment: @leandriis, i updated and added an example. I use tabularx because they always "just span the full textwidth". It is not possible for me to use a different environment inside tables, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

tabular* will fix the tabular's width to the textwidth.

For the tabular inside a tabular cell, you could use the multirow package. You can specify cells containing multiple rows/columns (and both) with it. Examples can be found
[here](https://texblog.org/2012/12/21/multi-column-and-multi-row-cells-in-latex-tables/).

Answer (score 1):

To obtain `X`  columns with lengths in a certain ratio, you have to use the syntax
`>\hsize=x_i\hsize}X`, where `x_i` is a coefficient for the i-th X column which is proportional  to the desired fraction of the total free length, and such that the sum of the coefficients is equal to the total number of X columns.

For example, to have the ratio 80/20 with two X columns, you would have to solve the (easy) linear system:

`x_1/80=x_2/40, x_1+x_2=2`, whence, in the table preamble:

`>{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}X`.

Comment: Thanks, if I knew the desired width ratio in advance, this would be the way to go.

Comment: If you don't know in advance, I'm afraid it would be by trial and error.